# Pandas Dataframe bad formating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I am trying to display a pandas DataFrame in tkinter python and all of the columns are misaligned.

First this function takes these 4 columns from my log table and converts it into DataFrame

```
def show_log():
    df = pandas.read_sql("SELECT id, user_id, book_id, action FROM library.log LIMIT 10", con=mydb)
    blankIndex = [''] * len(df)
    df.index = blankIndex
    return df
```

Then this function creates a tkinter label with the dataframe

```
   def show_log(self):
        self.label_show_log = tk.Label(self.master, text=fu.show_log(), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.label_show_log.pack()
```

This is the tkinter output I get - and it's ugly:

[image: This is the tkinter output I get - and it's ugly]

I want to make all of the columns and the data evenly aligned!
Thank you for any help! :)

Comment: You need to use a fixed width (or monospaced) font for the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a fixed width (or monospaced) font, for example "Courier New", for the label:

```py
   def show_log(self):
        self.label_show_log = tk.Label(self.master, text=fu.show_log(),
                                       borderwidth=2, relief="groove",
                                       font=("Courier New", 10))
        self.label_show_log.pack()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use pandastable to display dataframes in tkinter

> Install: pip install pandastable

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table

#Create DataFrame class
class DataFrameTable(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, df=pd.DataFrame()):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True) 
        self.table = Table(
            self, dataframe=df,
            showtoolbar=False,
            showstatusbar=True,
            editable=False)
        self.table.show()

#Tkinter window
root = Tk()
#Show Table
DataFrameTable(root, your_dataframe)
root.mainloop()
```